Google Apps Script sweet alert not running
would like alert to popup when we click 're-assign reviewer' to indicate a list of reviewers from Gsheet for the user to select from. however the sweet alert is not showing up when i run this script, the error seems to be due to InputOptionsPromise, how can i correct this please? i am completely new to Google Apps Script, please i would appreciate some help, thank you!
  if (action == 'Prepared') {

    Swal.fire({
      title: "Insert Google Drive Folder Link",
      input: 'text',
      inputPlaceholder: `Enter link for ${formName}`      
  }).then((result) => {
      if ((result.value).includes("drive.google.com/drive/folders/")) {
            Swal.fire({
              title: 'Please check reviewer',
              text: "Email will be sent to: " + newData[0]['Assigned Checker'],
              icon: 'info',
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
              cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
              confirmButtonText: 'Yes, send!',
              cancelButtonText: 'Change reviewer'
            }).then((checking) => {
              if (checking.isConfirmed) {
              //ACTION WHEN SEND IS CONFIRMED
              Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Task has been prepared',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1500
              })
            google.script.run.update_dashboard(id, newData[0], action, sheetName, result.value, newData[0]['Assigned Checker'].replace(' (cover)', ''));
              }
              else {
              Swal.fire({
                title: 'Select Reviewer',
                input: 'select',
                inputOptions: inputOptionsPromise,
                inputPlaceholder: 'Select Reviewer',
                showCancelButton: true,
                inputValidator: function(value) {
                  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    if (value != '') {
                      resolve();
                    } else {
                      reject('You need to select a reviewer')
                      alert('Select reviewer required')
                    }
                  })
                }
              }).then((address) => {
                if (address.isConfirmed) {
                Swal.fire({
                  type: 'success',
                  html: 'Email will be sent to: ' + address.value
                })
                google.script.run.update_dashboard(id, newData[0], action, sheetName, result.value, address.value);
                }
              })
              }
            })
      }
      else {
          Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: 'Please insert Google Drive Folder Link. Folder path is required.',
          color: '#716add',
        })
      }
  });
  return
  }
  else if (action != 'Prepared') {
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'success',
      title: 'Task has been ' + action,
      showConfirmButton: false,
      timer: 1500
    })
  google.script.run.update_dashboard(id, newData[0], action, sheetName, newData[0]['Link']);

  }
  
}

function tagPSC () {

  var id = $("#formID").val();
  Swal.fire({
    title: "Enter Pre-Submission Checklist ID:",
    text: "UID can be found in checklist tab",
    input: 'text',
    inputPlaceholder: 'e.g.: 3e44ead7-82c7-4782-a58c-471106c05d56',
    showCancelButton: true        
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.value.length == 36) {
        google.script.run.tag_psc_dashboard(id, result.value);
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'UID tagged successfully',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 1500
        })
    }
    else {
      Swal.fire({
      icon: 'error',
      title: 'Oops...',
      text: 'Please insert valid unique ID generated from Pre-Submission Checklist.',
      color: '#716add',
    })
  }
    
  });

}

function promiseLoadout () {
  waitFor(_ => selectLi != null && userMapping != null)
  .then(_ => 
    (promiseResolution(selectLi, userMapping, 'val'),
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
      var promiseOutput = {}
      JSON.parse(data).forEach(obj=>{
        promiseOutput[obj['userName']] = obj['userID'] + "@maribank.com.sg"
      })
      window.inputOptionsPromise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        // get your data and pass it to resolve()
        setTimeout(function () {
          resolve(promiseOutput)
        }, 2000)
      })
    }).convertToJson("Users"))
  );
}


function reassign () {

  var id = $("#formID").val();
  Swal.fire({  
  title: 'Re-Assign Maker or Checker?',  
  showDenyButton: true,  showCancelButton: false,  
  confirmButtonText: `Maker`,  
  denyButtonText: `Checker`,
  }).then((result) => {  
    /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */  
      if (result.isConfirmed) {    
          Swal.fire({
          title: 'Select new preparer',
          input: 'select',
          inputOptions: inputOptionsPromise,
          inputPlaceholder: 'Select new preparer',
          showCancelButton: true,
          inputValidator: function(value) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              if (value != '') {
                resolve();
              } else {
                reject('You need to select a preparer')
                alert('Select preparer required')
              }
            })
          }
        }).then((address) => {
          if (address.isConfirmed) {
          Swal.fire({
            type: 'success',
            html: 'Preparer has been changed to: ' + address.value
          })
          google.script.run.reassign_dashboard('maker', id, address.value);
          }
        })

      } else if (result.isDenied) {    
        
          Swal.fire({
          title: 'Select new reviewer',
          input: 'select',
          inputOptions: inputOptionsPromise,
          inputPlaceholder: 'Select new reviewer',
          showCancelButton: true,
          inputValidator: function(value) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              if (value != '') {
                resolve();
              } else {
                reject('You need to select a reviewer')
                alert('Select reviewer required')
              }
            })
          }
        }).then((address) => {
          if (address.isConfirmed) {
          Swal.fire({
            type: 'success',
            html: 'Reviewer has been changed to: ' + address.value
          })
          google.script.run.reassign_dashboard('checker', id, address.value);
          }
        })

    }
  });


}



Do not repost a question you already asked because you do not have answers; instead, edit the previous question. If the previous question was so wrong that it couldn't be fixed without changing it completely, ensure that the new question is different, i.e., make it more specific and tell us why the similar questions asked before don't meet your needs.
